# Htaccess redirect not invisible

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, url-rewriting, invisible

I've done many htaccess redirects, but for some reason this one doesn't redirect the subdomain to a subfolder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^((?!www\.)(.+)|(?:www\.)(.+))\.(timseverien\.nl)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? /subdomains/%2%3%5 [L]
```

When it redirects I can see `/subdomains/x/` in my url bar which I don't want.
The reason I have this in my htaccess is because my dearest host is a complete fuckup considering domains and subdomains.

So, my question is: Why is the redirect visible and what can I do to change it?

Comment: Try simplest rewrite rule first, possibly hardcode all values (e.g. `kitten.example.com/meow` => `/subdomains/kitten/meow`) and see if you will have the same result (visible redirect). BTW -- if it is visible -- what code is that (301, 302 etc)?

Comment: When I use this as htaccess: `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} minifier\.timseverien\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? www.timseverien.nl/subdomains/minifier [L]` and go to minifier.timseverien.nl it redirects me to minifier.timseverien.nl/subdomains/minifier which displays a 'document moved' so looks like a 302

Comment: That's because you have included domain name in target URL. If you have just URL (no domain name: `/subdomains/minifier` it should not do redirect, only rewrite aka "internal redirect"). Test it for those kind of URLs.

Comment: There's no difference. I've tried both ways, same result

Comment: 1) Can you please try target URL without leading slash? 2) You have some redirect directive somewhere else (via Apapche's directive `Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`, `RewiteRule` in another htaccess file maybe); Unlikely (you would be aware), but redirect can be done inside the page; Apache's specific config. In any case -- I see no obvious reasons why such rule should trigger 3xx redirect instead of rewrite. Would be great if you could enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`), but for this you need to edit config file... No other bright ideas, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the .htaccess, but in the DNS of my host. I'm moving the first of November!